# How to read data from database on checkbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox

I have a table with value bit type data include two value 0 and 1, i want to read into checkbox, I have code below but, if 0 or 1 it alway chose and put on checkbox. How to read it to checkbox? please help. Thank you very much.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Purchasing From ERPManualGuide", con);
SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
CheckBox5.Checked = reader1.Read();
```

Comment: You need to call reader.GetBoolean() after reading from database. Something like:
reader1.Read();
Checkbox5.Checked = reader1GetBoolean(i) 
(where i is you column number)

Answer (score 0):

See, here you are fetching only a single cell value from the database, so reader is not necessary in this case. I prefer you to use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) which will returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored. and are of type object so you need to cast them to boolean, so the code changes would be :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Purchasing From ERPManualGuide", con);
CheckBox5.Checked = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

You have to note few things additionally:

- `cmd`, `CheckBox5` etc are not good names for variables and controls, you should follow some naming standards, Take care while naming variables
- In this case the type of column `Purchasing` is convertible to boolean, which means it would be  `bit field` in database
- If you are in a situation of fetching more columns then go ahead with `SqlDataReader` instead for `ExecuteScalar()`
- In that case you have to check for `reader.HasRows` then access the value like this: `CheckBox5.Checked = (bool)reader1["Purchasing"];`

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn: Nice to hear that, happy to help you! Hope that you wont forget to mark it as accepted

Comment: Oh No! that's incorrect in this case. In my database I have a table, and there are two value 0 and 1. If use like that it will always checked into the checkbox when I load page.

Comment: what is the type of `Purchasing` in database

Comment: Purchasing is Bit type

Comment: Oh. I understand now. i converted the type of Purchasing in database to "int" and it OK. Thank you very much.! very happy by your help. How i can vote for you in this page, I'm a new member

Comment: Hi un-lucky, can you help me this problem, i have two value in 2 checkbox, how to pass that into 2 parameter in procedure